# Doctrine many to many with linktable code

Tags: doctrine, many-to-many

[image: schema]

I want to add a getHomeAddress() to a customer entity in doctrine using symfony wondering what the best practice would be

Answer (score 0):

Customer Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Addresses", inversedBy="customers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Customer_Addresses")
 */
private $addresses;
```

Addresses Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Customers", mappedBy="addresses")
 */
private $customers;
```

Customers Entity

```
$customers->getHomeAddress();
```

This codes for in entity mapping annotation, more information this address  Doctrine Association Mapping http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: How does this address the fact that the address_type_code is 'H', I was hoping to do this without the use of a object/entity manager. This is more of me being new to doctrine and looking for best practices.

if i need to use an entity manager could i add it as a reusable trait perhaps?